# Yarn install is failing

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, grpc-node

I know i shouldn't just throw a question like this and wish i can provide more information, but i am really no idea what it is and it also my first time encounter such issue (after change to new laptop), i think currently i can only provide the error message until someone ask me to provide further info..

When I run the command yarn install at last I am getting below error, tried to install grpc also

```
error /Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.13.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@18.12.1 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.23.3 and node@18.12.1 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.23.3/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
gyp info using node@18.12.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
gyp info using node@18.12.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.6 found at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3"
gyp info spawn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args \[
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.12.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.12.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.12.1/\<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args \]
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
gyp info using node@18.12.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args \[ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' \]
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
clang: warning: using sysroot for 'iPhoneSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX' \[-Wincompatible-sysroot\]
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.cc:19:
In file included from ../deps/grpc/include/grpc/support/port_platform.h:22:
../deps/grpc/include/grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h:201:9: warning: 'GRPC_ARES' macro redefined \[-Wmacro-redefined\]
\#define GRPC_ARES 0
^
\<command line\>:3:9: note: previous definition is here
\#define GRPC_ARES 1
^
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.cc:32:
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker_registry.h:26:
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker_factory.h:26:
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker.h:35:
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server.h:30:
In file included from ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address.h:26:
../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/port.h:211:2: error: "Must define exactly one of GRPC_POSIX_SOCKET, GRPC_WINSOCK_SOCKET, GRPC_CUSTOM_SOCKET"
\#error \
^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: \*\*\* \[Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o\] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:201:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v108-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.\<anonymous\> (/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v108-d
```

tried yarn install command

Answer (score 0):

You are using Node 18 and you are trying to install the `grpc` package, which was deprecated two years ago and does not support any version of Node greater than 14. The replacement for that package is `@grpc/grpc-js`.